# Checking dependencies of packages

Tags: makefile, sh

I am writing a script in which i want to check these listed packages are installed in linux-box or not?, then proceed for the further installation.

For Ex.

```
    subversion
    GCC compiler
    ncurses-dev
    gettext
    texinfo
    patch
    bison
    flex
    openssl
    libssl-dev
```

I didn't found any standard way to check dependencies please Help!

Comment: http://www.mirkopagliai.it/bash-scripting-check-for-and-install-missing-dependencies/ this would be really helpful

Comment: what is the question? If these packages are installed, how to find out if they are installed, how to find out which packages are installed or something about dependencies?

Comment: yes want to check whether packages are installed or not

Comment: If you just want to know if certain executables are available, akond's answer is fine.  If you want to use the package manager to check, then you have to specify what GNU/Linux distribution you're using, because there are different ways to do it on different types of systems.

Comment: You probably want to check version numbers as well.

Comment: I want to write a general script, it should be able to work in every OS @MadScientist.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that came to my mind is:

```
check-packages:
    which bison
    which svn
    which flex
```

and so forth.

Comment: `which` does not support for every OS

Comment: Why did you tag your question as linux?

Comment: i Removed it. Thanx  @akond